# Car Idles Really High Sometimes

Tags: battery, car, idle, throttle-body, fast-idle

I have a 2002 Ford Explorer 4.6l V8 (Automatic). I have this issue were randomly my car will idle high. I start it up and the rpms go to 2500 and eventually get down to 2000 which is a bug jump from my regular 900rpm. This causes my car to fight me when Im breaking as its trying to accelerate even though Im breaking. It also almost feels as if cruise control is on because I can let off the gas and it maintains if not gains speed. I have cleaned the throttle body and it did nothing. I plan on cleaning the iac soon. The wierd thing is if I disconect the battery for 30 minutes then re connect it the problem goes away for awhile. But eventually returns agian. If anyone could help me with this that would be great. Also there is no engine light.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked all the pipe work for splits that would cause an air leak (air being sucked in)?

Comment: No I haven't. If it was an air leak you think after "reseting" the ecm the problem would stop for a month or so? Wouldnt the issue still continue even after a "reset"?

Comment: Vacuum leaks are very fickle. They can come and go depending on temperature, movement, anything. When the idle is running high, wiggle and twist all the vacuum lines you can find.